# How to extract English words mix with other languages?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Japanese language dataset, where there is a column that is a mix of English and Japanese characters. I only want to keep the English words and remove the Japanese characters.

```
df['支払い方法'].head(10)
```

Outputs

```
0                カード可（JCB、AMEX、Diners）電子マネー不可
1                                         nan
2                                         nan
3                                         nan
4                                 カード可電子マネー不可
5    カード可（VISA、Master、JCB、AMEX、Diners）電子マネー不可
6                                         nan
7                                       カード不可
8           カード可（VISA、Master、JCB、AMEX、Diners）
9                                       カード不可
```

Now I only want to keep the English words like below:

```
0                               JCB, AMEX, Diners
1                                         nan
2                                         nan
3                                         nan
4                                         nan
5                         VISA. Master, JCB, AMEX, Diners
6                                         nan
7                                         nan
8                       VISA, Master, JCB, AMEX, Diners
9                                         nan
```

One way is maybe to keep only the words inside `()`, but I want to remove all ASCII characters. Any help?

Comment: `df[0].replace(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',' ',regex=True)` ? lots of dupes for this search for how to replace non latin characters.. or something to that effect. `df[0].replace(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',' ',regex=True).str.strip().str.replace(' ',',')` to replace the extra white space.

Comment: Could use something like this `''.join(re.findall(r'[\d\sa-zA-Z,]+',df.replace('、',', ')))`. Isn't perfect but could be a start.

Answer (score 0):

I think pandas `str.extract()` method will help here:

Using this as the input data:

```
カード可（JCB、AMEX、Diners）電子マネー不可
カード可電子マネー不可
カード可（VISA、Master、JCB、AMEX、Diners）電子マネー不可
カード不可
カード可（VISA、Master、JCB、AMEX、Diners）
カード不可
```

This code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)

# Pattern to match: a-z, whitespace, ',' and '、'
pattern = r'([a-zA-Z\s,、]+)' 
df[0].str.extract(pattern)
```

Returns:

```
0              JCB、AMEX、Diners
1                          NaN
2  VISA、Master、JCB、AMEX、Diners
3                          NaN
4  VISA、Master、JCB、AMEX、Diners
5                          NaN
```